# Java sorting collection/api

Tags: java, api, list, sorting, package

I am wondering what API or collection would be best to use for using scanner to search through a document, count the number of times a word appears and create an alphabetical list of both that and for each word a sublist of how many times it is followed by another word.

This is for a class, so please just point me in the right direction as I am completely new to Java and packages, but I don't want any actual coding tips, thank you.

Comment: Are you creating a markov chain? Looks like what you're describing is a frequency table.

Comment: I'd suggest using a `HashMap` to count the occurrences of each word. And another `HashMap` to count the 2-grams. CodeEval created somewhat similar challenge: http://codeeval.com/open_challenges/55/ (you'll need to register in order to view it)

Comment: Is this to create new random sentences/paragraphs from grammar encountered in some input text? I would go HashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you could do something like that with `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`. Essentially what you'll have a word, which is associated with a map that contains all the successive words along with their frequency (i.e., the number of times they appear). So what you'd have is:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> frequencyTable = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
```

For sorting, you could create a class that holds a word and its frequency. Then you can use a `TreeSet` with a comparator (or implement `compareTo` on your class) to enforce ordering. Then your map would look like this:

```
Map<String, TreeSet<Frequency>> frequencyTable = new HashMap<String, TreeSet<Frequency>>();
```

Assuming `Frequency` is the class that holds information about the string and the number of times it appears. The only difficulty here is looking up the word each time you need to update its frequency because you will have to iterate over the set.

Comment: this contains everything he is looking for, but does not easily expose the total number of times a word is used. It might be more java/oo to do Map<String, CLASS>, where class contains a total count, and the other rmap.

Comment: @Colin you are right. Totally forgot about the sorting part. I will try to edit. I am on my phone right now.

Answer (score 1):

See if its about Sorting........

Here are you few options...

1. Use **Collections.sort(T t)** along with **Comparable interface**, if you want to **sort in only
   one way.**
2. Use **Collection.sort(T t, Comparator c)** along with **Comparator interface to sort in more than one way.**
3. If **uniqueness is important**, you can also use **TreeSet with comparator**.